# WPF listview not changing with ItemSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a simple 2 column listview in WPF, but i have hit a brick wall.

I have the Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="asas" Height="220" Margin="10,90,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=missionCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Folder" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and the C# code:

```
public readonly ICollection<Mission> missionCollection = new ObservableCollection<Mission>();
foreach (var campaign in campaigns)
{
    if(campaign.id != "c1")
        continue;
    foreach(Mission mission in campaign.missionList)
        missionCollection.Add(mission);
}
```

This C# code is in the same window.

My problem is that the listview seems to be determined not to update when i add something to the binding.

I have read a lot of other questions regarding this, but none of the solutions i have found seemed to help me.

I was following this page: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1

Comment: If you initialise the collection with data does it display?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Out of frustration i tried to replicate EXACTLY what the page i linked to did.

I needed to add

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

To the window Xaml Element

But that was not enough, All elements that you try to access from a `DisplayMemberBinding` MUST have a `{ get; set; }` (even if it's empty just like that) After adding that to all properties of the `Mission` class and adding

```
private ObservableCollection<Mission> _missionCollection = new ObservableCollection<Mission>();
public ObservableCollection<Mission> MissionList
    {
        get { return _missionCollection; }
    }
```

To the window code, Everything is working smoothly

Comment: it has to have a get to be a public property can can only bind to public properties

Comment: I just read up on it, i finally get why people write blank assessors now, At least i learned something from this problem, thanks.

Comment: I set the DataContext to my viewmodel inside the Window constructor -- DataContext = vm;